# Finding prime numbers without exceeding time limits

Tags: c++, primes

Okay first things first. Yes, this question is from a programming contest. No, I am not trying to cheat because the contest has ended 4 hours ago. I am pretty sure that my code is correct but the contest's compiler said that it is giving wrong answers. I tried an other compiler and it said "Time Limit Exceeded".

So, firstly, can you please tell me if the code is right or not? [One compiler said it wasn't]

If yes, then how can I make it more time efficient? [Another compiler said it was exceeding time limit]

---

> PROBLEM A number is called a prime number if it is greater than 1 and
>   has no divisors other than 1 and itself. The first few prime numbers
>   are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13,.. and so on. Given an integer X, find the
>   smallest prime number which is not less than X
>
> Input: The first line contains the number of test cases T. T cases
>   follow. Each test case consists of an integer X in a separate line.
>
> Output: Output T lines, one for each case containing the smallest
>   prime number which is not less than X
>
> Constraints: 1 <= T <= 10 1 <= X <= 1,000,000
>
> Sample Input: 4 8 47 90 1130
>
> Sample Output: 11 47 97 1151

Here is my solution:

```
int main() 
{
    int n;
    long int x, i, a;
    bool isPrime; // This flag will test if number is prime or not?
    cin>>n; // Here "n" will represent the number of test cases
    while(n)
    {
        cin>>x; // "x" is the number to be tested for the nth case

        if(x<=2)
        {
            cout<<2<<endl; // All numbers smaller than 3 will have the smallest prime number as 2.
            continue;
        }
        for(i=x;i<=1000000;i++) // Should I have checked values of "i" for odd numbers only? I forgot to try that... Would it have helped in reducing time complexity?
        {
            isPrime=true;
            for(a=2; a<i; a++) // Okay I tried making it (i/2)+1 but then the compiler said that it was a wrong answer. I am skeptical though...
            {
                if(i%a==0 and i!=2)
                    isPrime=false;
            }
            if(isPrime==true)
            {
                cout<<i<<endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        n--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this on your machine ? Maybe the compiler reporting an error was in fact your programm running for too long (at least more than a time limit imposed by the challenge).

Comment: Yes I ran it on my computer and tried various test cases like: -5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 50 all these numbers got correct outputs. Also the provided test cases worked like a charm.

Comment: you should have use a cache for prime values already encountered. It may have speed up the process. Also you don't need to check every divisor up to i, only up to sqrt(i)

Comment: You said "Time Limit Exceeded", so it means your program took to much time, you need to increase performance.

Comment: "if(isPrime==true)" == "if(isPrime)"

Comment: @athabaska it is not problem, all compilers generates the same code out of that.

Comment: The program fails for X=1000000

Comment: Break out of the `for(a=2` loop if you have already determined that `isPrime=false;`.

Comment: Checking only odd numbers won't reduce the time complexity. It will probably reduce the run time of the algorithm.

Comment: dornhege: Thanks for that little tweak! I can't believe I missed that!
Also, why won't "checking only odd numbers" reduce the time complexity? [I thought runtime and time complexity is the same thing! Sorry, bear with me for asking such naive questions]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reduce confusion, make a function that checks whether a number is prime:

```
bool IsPrime(int x)
{
    isPrime=true;
    for(int a = 2; a < x; a++)
    {
        if (x % a == 0 && a != 2)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here, I didn't change your code, only restructured it. This is good, because this function is small, and any improvement to it is easy.

**Remove edge case**

There is no need to check `a == 2`, because you never call this function for 2. This makes inner loop smaller, providing better performance.

```
bool IsPrime(int x)
{
    isPrime=true;
    for(int a = 2; a < x; a++)
    {
        if (x % a == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Check fewer divisors**

It is a well-known fact, and easy to check, that it's enough to check divisors up to `sqrt(x)`. This gives much better performance!

```
bool IsPrime(int x)
{
    isPrime=true;
    for(int a = 2; a * a <= x; a++)
    {
        if (x % a == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

At this point your program will probably be accepted by the time-checker. If you want better performance still, you can constrain divisors even further.

**Check only prime divisors**

Well, not really prime, but it's good to limit checking at least to odd numbers.

```
bool IsPrime(int x)
{
    isPrime=true;
    static const int a_few_primes[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13};
    for (int a: a_few_primes)
    {
        if (x % a == 0)
            return false;
    }
    for(int a = 17; a * a <= x; a += 2)
    {
        if (x % a == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

A note on the Sieve of Eratosthenes, which some other answerers recommend: it's good, but maybe you don't really need it, given that the number of test cases is very small (10).

Edit: removed some flawed analysis of performance.

The sieve method requires at least 1000000 iterations to build the list of prime numbers.

The trial method requires less than 500 iterations per number, trying less than [114](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) numbers until it finds a prime, and it does it 10 times, so the number of iterations is less than 500*114*10=570000.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to solve it for you, but give you some hints.

1. Use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), which allows you to build up an array that you can afterwards use to know whether a number is prime in `O(1)`.
2. Build the Sieve array once before you read any numbers, then you can read numbers and check each of them in constant time. Performing the same calculations for each number is overkill.

Comment: As it is programming contest this won't work. Because you will need to make a prime map and this takes much time

Comment: @ST3 what do you mean?

Comment: @athabaska OP told that is contest style programming so you have limited time and memory, this won't work, I have been a few times in similar contests and I know that the rules are.

Comment: @mfontanini: Sir, would that work for large numbers too? Making an array of that magnitude? Like it might exceed the allotted memory?

Comment: @user2732146 if you want to store the whole array(1,000,000 elements), that will weight 3.8MB. That's not much at all. If that's too much, then you could try optimizing the algorithm. Using the sieve is the way to go.

Comment: @ST3 I have been in some programming contests as well and have used the Sieve several times successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Solving this problem without running out of time requires two things:

- Pre-computing the primes, and
- Using binary search

You need fewer than [78,500](http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.shtml) primes to precompute, so you do not have to get too fancy. The only thing that you must do to make it fast is not wasting time checking your candidate divisors against non-primes: use the primes that you have found so far to discover new primes. This [page has pseudocode for this approach](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Efficient_Prime_Number_Generating_Algorithms#PGsimple4).

The table of primes will be in ascending order because of the way that you discover your primes. For each test case, search through the table of primes using [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Although the linear search *may* work as well, there's no point in wasting much CPU cycles doing it when the sorting comes for free. Moreover, C++ Standard Library [has a convenient function for finding items in sorted containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound), so your search can be coded in a single line.

Answer (score 2):

You're failing on big numbers - for instance, the smallest prime that is not smaller than 1,000,000 is 1,000,003.
It's important to test edge cases.

And precompute the primes with something like the sieve of Eratosthenes to speed it up.